# Spring boot parent module not updating upon changes on child module

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot.  I have created a spring multi module project with spring boot version 2.2.5.RELEASE.

**ModuleA**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>modules</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>modules</name>
    <description>Module Services</description>

    <modules>
        <module>moduleA</module>
        <module>moduleB</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**ModuleB**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>modules</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.moduleA</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**ModuleC**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>modules</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.moduleB</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I make any modification on ModuleB or ModuleC, these are not reflected in ModuleA.

I have tried the following two methods:

1. spring-boot:run
2. versions:set versions:update-child-modules -DnewVersion=0.0.2 -DprocessAllModules

How do I make the parent module update itself when updating sub-modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modules should be organized in directories in the following structure:

```
module A
|___ module B
|___ module C
```

Note: In this setup `module A` is used only for module management. So, no sources except `pom.xml` should be defined in `module A`.

- If you need only version propagation, then define dependencies for `module B` and `module C` in dependency management section of `module A pom.xml` and skip `<version>` in child modules:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- other dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>your-package-here</groupId>
      <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>your-package-here</groupId>
      <artifactId>moduleC</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

- If you want the changes in `module B` become available in `module C` - you should define artifacts for in `module A` (as in case above) and add dependency on `module B` in `module C pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- other dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>your-package-here</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: thanks @Oleksii Zghurskyi, the culprit is src folder that persent in module A. Once I deleted now my child module is getting updated. Thank you so much for your help to resolve this issue